# How to attach a modal with it's own click event to a dynamically created span - having to click newly added items twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building upon a TODO list in HTML and Javascript. I have added a third party modal by Paul Underwood. The modal is attached as a class to an element and contains its own click handler.

I have a `span` inside a list item and when I click on it it works fine for items already in the HTML. However I have to click twice for a newly added list item.

```
$("ul").append("<li><span><i class='fa fa-trash'></i></span><span class='paulund_modal'><i class='fa fa-angle-right'></i></span>" + todoText + "</li>");
```

Additionally, if I don't call `$(this).pauland_modal_box()` inside a click handler it won't get shown at all despite the fact the class is added in the html string of the append method above:

```
$("ul").on("click", "span:nth-child(2)", function(event) {
  // Show pop-up here...
  $(this).paulund_modal_box();
});
```

Comment: Assuming you're referring to [this library](https://paulund.co.uk/how-to-create-a-simple-modal-box-with-jquery) then it's massively outdated, as can be seen from the behaviour you describe above. I'd strongly suggest you use a better one.

Comment: Ah, ok, so the behaviour stems from the architecture or design pattern employed in the plug-in! (Yes it is that library).